# Falha ao popular um gridView

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-6, gridview

Estou tendo problemas ao exibir uma gridView, ela não esta exibindo os dados certos, parece que esta tentando exibir verticalmente, já troquei a propriedade Gridline para horizontal, both e agora esta Nome, igual a outra gridView que tenho funcionando.
Esta minha gridView esta sendo populada com informações vinda da base de dados. A minha gridView é essa:

```
     <asp:GridView ID="gridacao" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" ToolTip="Valores Atualizados das ações" Width="344px">
         <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="Gainsboro" />
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
     </asp:GridView>
```

na parte .cs esta assim:

```
public partial class ExibeAcao : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string cd;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                exibirAcao();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ce1)
        {

            throw new Exception(ce1.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    private void exibirAcao()
    {
        try
        {
            cd = "PETR4";
            Trataformes tf = new Trataformes();
            this.gridacao = tf.mostraAcao(cd, ref gridacao);
        }
        catch (Exception e2)
        {

            throw new Exception(e2.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
    protected void gridacao_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

}

O método mostrAcao() é esse:

```
public GridView mostraAcao(string cd, ref GridView gv)
    {
        try
        {
            ManipulaBanco mp = new ManipulaBanco();
            return mp.exibeAcao(cd, ref gv);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

e o método retira da base de dados é esse:

```
 public GridView exibeAcao(string cod, ref GridView tb)
    {
        try
        {
            bancotccEntities bc = new bancotccEntities();
            var pa = from ac in bc.acao
                     where ac.codigo == cod
                     select new
                     {
                         Ação = ac.codigo,
                         Empresa = ac.empresa,
                         Tipo = ac.tipo,
                         Data = ac.data,
                         Hora = ac.hora,
                         Abertura = ac.abertura,
                         Maxima = ac.maxima,
                         Minima = ac.minima,
                         Média = ac.medio,
                         Valor = ac.fechamento,
                         fechamento_Ontem = ac.f_anterior,
                         Volume_de_Ações = ac.volume,
                         Valor_Negociado = ac.v_financeiro,
                         Variação = ac.variacao,
                         Fase = ac.fase
                     };
            tb.DataSource = pa.ToString();
            tb.DataBind();
            return tb;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

estou obtenho o resultado abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que fosse exibido de maneira horizontal, 
alguém sabe como?

Comment: `tb.DataSource = pa.ToString();` ta errado aqui, não seria
`tb.DataSource = pa.ToList();`

Comment: É mesmo!! Método errado, só que agora não esta exibindo nada.

Comment: Breakpoint é a única solução ...

Comment: Primeira coisa que você faz é isso `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` coloque `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` se carregar era isso.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifique para o seguinte:

```
          var pa = from ac in bc.acao
                 where ac.codigo == cod
                 select new
                 {
                     Ação = ac.codigo,
                     Empresa = ac.empresa,
                     Tipo = ac.tipo,
                     Data = ac.data,
                     Hora = ac.hora,
                     Abertura = ac.abertura,
                     Maxima = ac.maxima,
                     Minima = ac.minima,
                     Média = ac.medio,
                     Valor = ac.fechamento,
                     fechamento_Ontem = ac.f_anterior,
                     Volume_de_Ações = ac.volume,
                     Valor_Negociado = ac.v_financeiro,
                     Variação = ac.variacao,
                     Fase = ac.fase
                 };
        tb.DataSource = pa.ToList();
        tb.DataBind();
```

---

Como as colunas não apareceram, possivelmente será necessário implementar um gerador automático de colunas para a sua `GridView`

### 1. Declare uma classe `DynamicTemplate`

```
public class DynamicTemplate : System.Web.UI.ITemplate
```

### 2. Declare um construtor em que seja configurado o tipo do item

```
public DynamicTemplate(System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemType type)
{
    templateType = type;
}
```

### 3. Crie um método na sua classe comum que popule a GridView

```
public void AddControl(WebControl wbControl, 
            String BindPropertyName, String BindExpression)
{
    htControls.Add(htControls.Count, wbControl);
    htBindPropertiesNames.Add(htBindPropertiesNames.Count, BindPropertyName);
    htBindExpression.Add(htBindExpression.Count, BindExpression);
}
```

### 5. Defina outro método que configure o container

```
public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
{
    PlaceHolder ph = new PlaceHolder();
    for (int i = 0; i < htControls.Count; i++)
    {
        //clone control 
        Control cntrl = CloneControl((Control)htControls[i]);
        switch (templateType)
        {
            case ListItemType.Header:
                break;
            case ListItemType.Item:
                ph.Controls.Add(cntrl);
                break;
            case ListItemType.AlternatingItem:
                ph.Controls.Add(cntrl);
                ph.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Item_DataBinding);
                break;
            case ListItemType.Footer:
                break;
        }
    }
    ph.DataBinding += new EventHandler(Item_DataBinding);
    container.Controls.Add(ph);
}
```

### 6. Use da seguinte forma

```
foreach (var propriedade in pa.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    TemplateField t = new TemplateField();
    DynamicTemplate mt = new DynamicTemplate(ListItemType.Item);
    TextBox t1 = new TextBox();
    t1.ID = propriedade.GetName();
    t1.Visible = true;
    t1.Text = propriedade.GetName();
    mt.AddControl(t1, "Text", propriedade.GetName());

    BoundField bf = new BoundField();

    bf.DataField = propriedade.GetName();
    bf.HeaderText = propriedade.GetName();

    tb.Columns.Add(mt);
    tb.Columns.Add(bf);
}
```

Fonte: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17078/Dynamically-Adding-Template-Columns-to-a-GridView

Comment: Alterei o fina do código de Tostring() para ToList(), mas agora não esta aparecendo nada.

Comment: @user9090 Possivelmente você tem que adicionar as colunas dinamicamente. Modifiquei minha resposta.

Comment: consegui! ainda bem que não foi preciso  adicionar as colunas dinamicamente, era, só alterar a propriedade citada pelo Harry. Obrigado pela ajuda pessoal. Pra falar a verdade tenho que ler mais sobre como  gerar as colunas dinamicamente, pois nunca se sabe quando vai precisar.